# How to disable right mouse button dragging in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

I don't want to have the right mouse button drag and drop behavior, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The code in Forge Viewer that controls this behavior (orbiting on left button down or right button down) is encapsulated in the `OrbitDollyPanTool` which is one of the default tools added to the viewer's "tool stack" during its initialization. Unfortunately the `OrbitDollyPanTool` does not provide any configuration options for disabling the camera orbit so you would have to implement your own viewer tool (see this blog post: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-tools-forge-viewer), and handle/capture the right mouse button event yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks, I used setNavigationLockSettings to disable drag and drop